# Matchings in infinite, not necessarily bipartite, graphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Aharoni, Nash-Williams, and Shelah have [extended](https://academic.oup.com/plms/article/s3-47/1/43/1545494) the famous [marriage theorem for finite bipartite graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) due to Hall to arbitrary graphs.

Is there a similar generalization of [Tutte's theorem on perfect matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem) in finite simple, undirected graphs to arbitrary simple, undirected graphs?

Comment: I found this: Aharoni: Tutte for countable https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895684900522 Also the general case https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82044729.pdf

Comment: That's wonderful thanks @PéterKomjáth - can you post this as an answer so we can close this thread?